# Azure RoleEntryPoint not called?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-roles

I've deployed my solution to an Azure CloudService using SDK version 2.6. 
The solution is running fine and now I want to configure some IIS settings from the RoleEntryPoint (like keeping the Threadpool always running).

Whatever I do, it seems that my RoleEntryPoint is never called. 
I am trying to trace information, I am throwing exceptions, I am even returning "false" in OnStart(). 
I deploy my package, the Cloudservice instances restart and everything is fine.

This is my simple class:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Elmah;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Cloud.WindowsAzure;

namespace SitefinityWebApp
{
public class AzureWebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{

    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Entering Run method");
        Trace.TraceInformation("Run");

        base.Run();
    }
    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        return false;
        Trace.WriteLine("Entering OnStart method");
        Trace.TraceInformation("OnStart");

        throw new System.ApplicationException("you are going down!");

        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
}
```

This class is in my main WebRole-Assembly. 
After deploying I tried "Reimaging" and restarting the VM. Both should be unnecessary but I wanted to make sure that the role gets a chance to call the RoleEntryPoint.

Any idea why the code is not called? I understand that returning "false" from the OnStart should have the effect that the role doesn't start at all? Why does the role start?

Comment: What if you rename the class name to `WebRole`?

Comment: @haim770: I haven't tried yet. Is there any indication that the name of the class is important? So far I read everywhere that Azure is using reflection to find the first class inheriting from RoleEntryPoint?

Comment: I read the same thing, but they're always using `WebRole` so, maybe...

Comment: Did you find solution to that issue yet ?

Comment: @MohamedAbed: No, sadly, I didn't. I have still no clue why the code is not called. Perhaps I should start a bounty.

Comment: @Sparhawk We found the issue, turns out we used a different version of one of the azure dlls in web.config, make sure you bind to correct versions and correct any binding redirect

Answer (score 2):

Our `RoleEntryPoint` was also not starting for the Azure Cloud Service Web Role. To fix this issue - the following steps worked for us:

#### Fix RoleEntryPoint not getting called

1. Remove All **Project References** in your Web Role to Azure, and remove the `packages.config`
2. Remove the current Web Role from your **Azure Project** (***ccproj***)
3. Re-add your Web Role to the **Azure Project** (*this re-adds the dependencies*)
4. Observe the updated `packages.config` and **Project References**.
5. In your Web Role, Ensure `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime` **Project Reference** has `Copy Local = true`

@mohamed-abed led us to this solution, we had a version mismatch between the [Azure SDK](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/) and the [unofficial nuget package for Azure Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unofficial.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime/).

The essential rule is that your **CCPROJ** `ProductVersion` should match the **Assembly** version referenced in your Web Role or the `RoleEntryPoint` will not be invoked.